# Powershell: Find a certificate in Userstore, based on Template

Tags: powershell, templates, certificate

after a week of googling and reading through StackOverflow and tons of other websites, I still couldn't get the answer to my question, or the answers I found didn't work.

I need to find the thumbprint of a certificate of the User Store. The cert has to be issued from a certain template.
If there are more then one cert, I would need all thumbprints.

I do have the certificate template name and the oid of it, but I still couldn't combine it to a query...

I started with something like

> Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Where { $_.Extensions.Format(1) -like 'xyz' }

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Where-Object { $_.Extensions.OID.FriendlyName -eq  'Certificate Template Information'}
```

If not, try this also, this retrieves the OID on all the certs:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | ForEach-Object { $_.Extensions.OID }
```

Comment: Nope, there are 2 (different) certs in the store, if I try the above PS line the result is empty, no matter which template name I use.

Comment: Don't change the above text - 'Certificate Template Information' is a value field. If you run the command above exactly as it is do you get any values? - I've edited also for another comamnd to get more info. Unfortunately I'm at home today so don't have any certs in my local store to test further.

Comment: The first commad doesn't give any output. The second one lists some template name, but it seems, those are only the build-in one, and not the custom template I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old, but you were *nearly* there. It seems like you were missing the wildcards `*` around the search text in your `-like` clause.

As an example, a certificate is stored in the variable `$cert`.

`$cert.ExtendedProperties.format(1)` consists of the certificate details formatted *exactly* as they will be displayed in the GUI Certificate Details tab. It's an array of strings. The first string object in the array (object `[0]`) contains the template details prepended with "Template=", plus two more lines of text.

```
$cert.extensions.format(1)[0]

Template=Code Signing(1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.10842032.6818741.11815602.4385420.9182287.54.5173773.13456390)
Major Version Number=101
Minor Version Number=6
```

If the filter was `| Where { $_.Extensions.Format(1) -like "Code Signing"}`, it would not find that substring, since it's expecting the *entire* string to simply be the word `Code Signing`.

In summary, to search for certificates by template name, either wrap the template name in a `-like` clause with wildcards (`-like "*Code Signing*"`), or use `-match` (I prefer the latter).

```
$certs = Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | Where { $_.Extensions.format(1) -match "Code Signing"}
$certs | ft Thumbprint,NotAfter -Auto

Thumbprint                               NotAfter
----------                               --------
FA6F92811B774C470C42E1AF6611111111111111 2022-02-02 05:25:23
5F88EF2FF6CAA1E0709C9E2207FFFFFFFFFFFFFF 2021-03-28 22:06:14
```

To check the results, you can do a `Foreach` on the `$certs` collection and output `$cert.extensions.format(1)[0]` to validate the template name.

Comment: For a non-english installation it might be better to use [OID](http://oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3&a=display)  `Get-ChildItem 'Cert:\CurrentUser\My\' | Where-Object { $_.Extensions.format(1) -match "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3"   }` you could also append `-and $_.Subject -cmatch $((Get-ADUser -Identity $env:USERNAME -Property SurName).surname)`

Comment: Yes, if you have the OID, that's often more useful, but the point about using wildcards if you're searching by *partial* template name, or (preferably, in my opinion) `match`, remains the same whatever language the templates are named in. Whichever is convenient, really!